# Go.js Copy Paste not work

Tags: javascript, gojs

I am using go.js library for diagrams.
I want to implement the copy paste functionality. I have tried builtin functions for copy and paste.

The problem with these methods are that they only copy selected node from canvas. But i want to copy also childNodes of that selected node.

Anyone here for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do you know about the CommandHandler.copiesTree property? Setting this to true may be sufficient for your purposes.
http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/CommandHandler.html#copiesTree

```
  $(go.Diagram, ...,
    { ...,
      "commandHandler.copiesTree": true
    })
```

The CommandHandler.copiesParentKey might also be useful if you are working with a TreeModel and want the copied subtree to be added to the current parent.

Second, if you want to copy nodes and links programmatically, you can call Node.findTreeParts and Diagram.copyParts.
http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Node.html#findTreeParts
http://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#copyParts

**Reference**
http://forum.nwoods.com/t/go-js-copy-paste-tree-not-work/6412/2

Comment: No problem, I just made the changes, that were necessary.